# gnuplot: how to generate smooth density plots from a distribution?

Tags: gnuplot, density-plot

I would like to make a density plot from a distribution like [the second subfigure](https://clauswilke.com/dataviz/directory-of-visualizations.html) in the following:

[image: example]

Here is what I tried:

```
unset key

set yrange [0:]
set ytics 5

set print $data
do for [i = 1:100] { print rand(0)*10 }
unset print

binwidth = 1
set boxwidth 0.8*binwidth
# set fill style of bins
set style fill solid 0.5
# define macro for plotting the histogram
hist = 'u (binwidth*(floor(($1)/binwidth)+0.5)):(1.0) smooth freq w boxes'

density = 'u (binwidth*(floor(($1)/binwidth)+0.5)):(1.0) smooth freq with filledcurves y=0'

plot $data @density
```

[image]

It is mainly based on a histogram by adding `with filledcurves`, but **a clear difference is that the resulting figure is not smooth at all**.

So, how can I generate smooth density plots from a distribution? Is there any interpolation function that can be used in gnuplot?

Comment: It's not clear to me why you want to smooth this type of data. You have discrete data in discrete bins, why not simply plotting them as bars as broad as they are? As I understand you don't have an analytical model or a mathematical function. Why do you want to give the impression that you have data in infinitesimal bins?

Answer (score 0):

I found `kernel density estimate` in gnuplot can be helpful here.

```
plot $data u 1:(1/100.) s kdens bandwidth 1 with filledcurves y=0
```

[image]